# Finding a Dataset That Is No Longer Available?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to follow this tutorial on data visualization with R (https://rpubs.com/brandonkopp/creating-a-treemap-in-r), but the dataset being used is no longer available:

```
 url <- "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2017/assets/outlays.csv"
 outlays <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2017/assets/outlays.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Using the "Wayback Machine", I was able to find an archived version of this website: https://web.archive.org/web/20160705194932/https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2017/assets/outlays.csv

The data on this website is stored in the following form:

```
Agency Code,Agency Name,Bureau Code,Bureau Name,Account Code,Account Name,Treasury Agency Code,Subfunction Code,Subfunction Title,BEA Category,Grant/non-grant split,On- or Off- Budget,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,TQ,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021
001,Legislative Branch,00,Legislative Branch,,"Receipts, Central fiscal operations",,803,Central fiscal operations,Mandatory,Nongrant,On-budget,-628,-390,-469,-413,-410,-722,-464,-522,-439,-360,-343,-427,-539,-307,-287,-132,-429,-385,-726,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
001,Legislative Branch,00,Legislative Branch,,"Receipts, Central fiscal operations",,908,Other interest,Net interest,Nongrant,On-budget,0,0,0,-8,-7,-7,-7,-6,-6,-6,-5,-4,-4,-4,-30,-17,-104,-61,-548,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
001,Legislative Branch,00,Legislative Branch,241400,Charges for services to trust funds,,803,Central fiscal operations,Mandatory,Nongrant,On-budget,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-32,-40,-24,0,-26,-50,0,-28,-31,-16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
001,Legislative Branch,05,Senate,0000,Senate,00,801,Legislative functions,Discretionary,Nongrant,On-budget,"26,946","29,310","29,914","33,261","35,388","38,060","42,441","47,619","57,585","65,050","74,140","78,870","93,066","102,237","123,851","31,104","138,507","158,208","169,454","183,890","195,467","213,229","227,439",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am not sure how I can take the data in this format and then import it into R.

Can someone please suggest how to do this? Or perhaps I am making this problem too complicated and this dataset actually might be available somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: That is an interesting approach to outdated data links that I never considered. I'll have to use that next time that comes up.

Comment: No problem! I am glad I could also provide some help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `read.csv`. Use the link you get when you select *<right click> >> This Frame >> Show only this frame.*

```
data <- read.csv('https://web.archive.org/web/20160705194932if_/https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2017/assets/outlays.csv')
str(data)
# 'data.frame': 5086 obs. of  73 variables:
#   $ Agency.Code          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Agency.Name          : chr  "Legislative Branch" "Legislative Branch" "Legislative Branch" "Legislative Branch" ...
# $ Bureau.Code          : int  0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
# $ Bureau.Name          : chr  "Legislative Branch" "Legislative Branch" "Legislative Branch" "Senate" ...
# $ Account.Code         : int  NA NA 241400 0 100 101 107 108 110 115 ...
# $ Account.Name         : chr  "Receipts, Central fiscal operations" "Receipts, Central fiscal operations" "Charges for services to trust funds" "Senate" ...
# $ Treasury.Agency.Code : int  NA NA NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ Subfunction.Code     : int  803 908 803 801 801 801 801 801 801 801 ...
# $ Subfunction.Title    : chr  "Central fiscal operations" "Other interest" "Central fiscal operations" "Legislative functions" ...
# $ BEA.Category         : chr  "Mandatory" "Net interest" "Mandatory" "Discretionary" ...
# $ Grant.non.grant.split: chr  "Nongrant" "Nongrant" "Nongrant" "Nongrant" ...
# $ On..or.Off..Budget   : chr  "On-budget" "On-budget" "On-budget" "On-budget" ...
# $ X1962                : chr  "-628" "0" "0" "26,946" ...
# $ X1963                : chr  "-390" "0" "0" "29,310" ...
# $ X1964                : chr  "-469" "0" "0" "29,914" ...
# $ X1965                : chr  "-413" "-8" "0" "33,261" ...
# $ X1966                : chr  "-410" "-7" "0" "35,388" ...
# $ X1967                : chr  "-722" "-7" "0" "38,060" ...
# $ X1968                : chr  "-464" "-7" "0" "42,441" ...
# $ X1969                : chr  "-522" "-6" "-32" "47,619" ...
# $ X1970                : chr  "-439" "-6" "-40" "57,585" ...
# $ X1971                : chr  "-360" "-6" "-24" "65,050" ...
# $ X1972                : chr  "-343" "-5" "0" "74,140" ...
# $ X1973                : chr  "-427" "-4" "-26" "78,870" ...
# $ X1974                : chr  "-539" "-4" "-50" "93,066" ...
# $ X1975                : chr  "-307" "-4" "0" "102,237" ...
# $ X1976                : chr  "-287" "-30" "-28" "123,851" ...
# $ TQ                   : chr  "-132" "-17" "-31" "31,104" ...
# $ X1977                : chr  "-429" "-104" "-16" "138,507" ...
# $ X1978                : chr  "-385" "-61" "0" "158,208" ...
# $ X1979                : chr  "-726" "-548" "0" "169,454" ...
# $ X1980                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "183,890" ...
# $ X1981                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "195,467" ...
# $ X1982                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "213,229" ...
# $ X1983                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "227,439" ...
# $ X1984                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1985                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1986                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1987                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1988                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1989                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1990                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1991                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1992                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1993                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1994                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1995                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1996                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1997                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1998                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X1999                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2000                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2001                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2002                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2003                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2004                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2005                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2006                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2007                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2008                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2009                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2010                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2011                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2012                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2013                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2014                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2015                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2016                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2017                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2018                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2019                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2020                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
# $ X2021                : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Were you able to get the visualization to work?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Welcome! No, the rpubs site won't open for me.

Comment: Thanks again! I posted the follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165521/r-error-index-contains-invalid-column-names